# Multiple models - no data retrieved

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I am trying to use multiple models in my view. My view is a single items and the models are lists displayed within the view using tabs.

in my controller I added the setModel in the display function

```
class ComplianceControllerCompliance extends JControllerForm
{
    public function display( $cachable = false, $urlparam = array() )
    {       
        $view = $this->getView( 'myview', 'html' );
        $view->setModel( $this->getModel( 'mymodel' ), true );

        $view->setModel( $this->getModel( 'content' ) );

        $view->display();
    }
```

In my view I try to access the needed information like this

```
$this->content_items        = $this->get( 'Items', 'content' );
$this->content_pagination   = $this->get( 'Pagination', 'content' );
$this->content_state        = $this->get( 'State', 'content' );
```

but I dont get any information.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis of working with multiple models is finding a way to get an instance of each model. The most likely issue is that `$this->getModel('yourmodelname')` returns false.

Test that this part works:

```
$testModel = $this->getModel('yourmodelname');
var_dump($testModel);
```

I guess you have already studied the [Using multiple models in an MVC component article](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_multiple_models_in_an_MVC_component).

Comment: Yes, I did. So I set a breakpoint in my display function in my controller, but it seems as I never get there?! And the added dump didn't get me any info.

Comment: OK, reason for this is that probably you are not calling the controller, but the view. Your URL should look like: `index.php?option=com_example&task=display` NOT `index.php?option=com_example&view=yourviewname`. Does that make sense?

Comment: It would, but according to [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Absolute_Basics_of_How_a_Component_Functions) without a task the default task is "view". However I tried your idea, but sadly it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are in a subcontroller, try `index.php?option=com_example&task=controllername.display`. Last but not least, use a debugger.

Comment: This did the trick, now I am getting to the display function and it seems to work as intended, thanks a lot.  What I still don't get is why do i need to call task=controller.display shouldn't the controller be called whenever the display task is used?

Comment: AFAIK when you don't specify a task, the default task is 'default'. When you don't specify the controller (like `task=controllername.display`) Joomla calls the default controller (controller.php), not the subcontroller you want to have. Hope this make sense. Nevertheless, use a debugger to better understand what Joomla does.

Comment: For more Joomla specific questions, refer to the Joomla Q&A at stackexchange: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/